# On cookie expire, delete MySQL row

Tags: php

I want to delete the row on the MySQL table corresponding with the cookie when the cookie expires or is deleted. How would I do this using PHP?

Comment: Good luck with that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that directly. The best hope you have is to have an `expires` column in your database, which saves the date/time at which the cookie expires, then you could have a cron script to delete the expired rows.

Comment: What if a the cookie were to be deleted beforehand? Oh well?

Comment: You have no way of knowing that - it's sort of the point of deleting cookies.

Comment: Just one more question.. If the user were to log out of session, uncheck remember me and login again, could I maybe use that as a checking method and run a delete query? EDIT: Nevermind I realize even if they created a new cookie the old row wouldn't be used and expire in time.